# Динамическое именование листов PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

возникла проблема с именованием листов. Выгружаю с базы категории, хочу чтобы каждой категории соответствовал отдельный лист, создаю без проблем, но, как только доходит дело до присвоения имени листу, тут уже проблемы, первое я решил что максимальная длина имени, 30 символов, хорошо, обрезаю строку до 30 символов, всё равно не получается, стоит обрезать строку до 10 символов, выводит, но имена содержат только 5 символов, кто сталкивался с данной проблемой, как её решить?

```
Таблица категорий
7   Смесители на раковину
8   Смесители для ванны и душа
9   Душевые системы
10  Комплектующие для душа
11  Смесители для кухни
12  Сифоны и донные клапаны
13  Смесители для гигиенического душа
14  Аксессуары
15  Полотенцесушители
16  Смесители на борт ванны
17  Смеситель для биде
```

Сам код

```
$r=$this->get_typ();
    $is=0;
    foreach ($r as $res){
        if ($is!=0){
            $objPHPExcel->createSheet();
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($is);
            $active_sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
        }
        $is++;
        $str=substr($res['nazv'], 0, 10);
        $active_sheet->setTitle($str);
```

Comment: Решил уже вопрос, вместо substr нужно использовать mb_substr

Comment: попробуйте phpspreadsheet вместо phpExcel, который закрыт и не поддерживается.